# Navbar link scroll to top

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

What I want to do is that when "Home" is clicked on the navbar, it should scroll to the top of the page, but I can't seem to get anything working. I'm to get it to work on the same .html so I'm using  on the same page

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container text-center">
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#feedback">Feedback</a></li>
                <li><a href="#about">About me</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>

<script>
    $("#home").on("click", function() {
        $("body").scrollTop(0);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Html doesn't need jquery to do this. Just write in your url #home and give body id "home" and it will point to that id and since it's body it will scroll up to the top. No need for jquery unless you don't want to use it for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

Here you can do with this code.

You can't use `#home` directly in jQuery because it is not a `id`.

So you should use it like this `$("a[href='#home']").on("click", function() {`

Hope this example will helps you.

```js
$("a[href='#home']").on("click", function() {
    $('body').animate({
            scrollTop: 0
    },
    500); //this will helps you to smooth scroll to top
});
```

```css
body {
height: 500px;
}
nav {
position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container text-center">
            <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#feedback">Feedback</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#about">About me</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes this code won't work unfortunately, try:

```
$("a[href='#home']").click(function(){
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop : 0},800);
    return false;
});
```

Best wishes

Answer (score 0):

I dont think `body` have scroll bar. You need to find the `div` containts the scroll bar. Just simple right click the scroll bar and Inspec it